# Speed up object creation

Tags: django

I have an API call which return an json file like 1000s of this:

```
{
    "date": "2021-02-27T00:00:00+00:00",
    "value": 11590,
    "countryName": "Netherlands",
    "countryCode": "NL"
},
{
    "date": "2021-02-27T00:00:00+00:00",
    "value": 88,
    "countryName": "Belgium",
    "countryCode": "BE"
}
```

I have some code which creates entries and links it through a foreign key:

```
for country in response['countryPlots']:
    country['parent'] = parent.pk
    countrydata = CountrySerializer(data=country)
    countrydata.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    countrydata.save()
```

But it's too slow. I have to do millions of these creations.

Comment: Customizing the ListSerializer may help. Doc is here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer

Comment: Have you tried using bulk_create()? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create